# Unwanted space between grid elements CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a webpage that includes 3 columns of varying sizes. The sizes are how I want them, however there is some unwanted space between the leftmost column and the middle column. Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qme65unj/

I have tried setting padding, margins, etc. to 0 to no avail.

I've adjusted the max-width of the leftmost column to the size I would like, however it is still leaving open blank space between itself and the middle column. I would like the middle column to either stretch or simply move to be right next to the right side of the left column.

```css
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
        padding: 0;
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .coursesGridItem {
        background-color: red;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: left;
        max-width: 42.5%;
        grid-column-gap: 0;
        grid-row-gap: 0;
    }

    .assignmentGridItem
    {
        background-color: blue;
        padding: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        grid-column-gap: 0;
        grid-row-gap: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .upcomingGridItem
    {
        background-color: yellow;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .addCourseBtn
    {
        background-color: white;
        width: 125px;
        height: 45px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-size: 17px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }

    .addCourseBtn:hover
    {
        background-color: #c95100;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="mainBodyRowStudent" class="grid-container">
            <div class="coursesGridItem" style="border-right: 2px solid #c95100">
                <h2>Courses</h2>
                <button id="addCourse" class="addCourseBtn">+ Add Course</button>
            </div>

            <div class="assignmentGridItem">
                <h2>Assignments</h2>
                <h3>Current</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="upcomingGridItem">
                <h2>Upcoming</h2>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How about removing `max-width: 42.5%;`?

Comment: @Stickers When I do that, the size of the column is much bigger than I want. It makes all 3 columns equal but I want the leftmost column to be smaller in width than the other 2.

Comment: Something like `grid-template-columns: 20% auto auto;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .grid-container change `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;` to `grid-template-columns: 15% auto auto;` and remove the `max-width: 42.5%` from .coursesGridItem

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize grid-template-columns did that.

Comment: No problem, heres a good guid on css grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/